# Given a poset of bounded height and an element, find its maximal chain in subquadratic time

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, order-theory

Given a poset $P$ of height $|P|-k$, and an element $x \in P$, what is the computational complexity of finding the largest chain in which $x$ lies?

It is easy to do the above in time quadratic with respect to the size of the poset. For all $y \geq x$, find all $z \geq y \geq x$. Rinse and repeat until no more can be found, and do the same for $y \leq x$. Something of this sort should be able to return the chain in $O(|P|^2)$.

Can we do any better? The height restriction should put restrictions on the structure and adjacency matrix that could help...

Comment: finding the Cardinality of the chain is the closest I can come as a possibility.

Comment: I think you can do it for bounded height, but I'm still interested in general what the answer is. For bounded height you have k+1 possible local minima, each of which can be found in linear time. From there you can run a linear time algorithm to walk up up the chain to one of k+1 possible local maxima, then fill in all points between. We can rinse and repeat some function in k times to find the right one since we know the height. Edit: unless filling is not linear... I have to check that

Comment: Actually it may not even be possible for bounded height...